# Save Image files and some text together as one file/object

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-image, transfer

I created an android test app with camera interface in which I want to save a text message and image file as one object. I am able to enter message, call the camera,take a picture and also populate the image in the image view on the app. Now I want to save them as one single record/object so that I can transfer it over network using protocol such as ftp. How to save image file and text together as one single file/object? Could someone please tell me how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you consider using the exif tags ?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possibilities, and it depends to some extent on what will be consuming the file after it is transferred. You could, for instance, simply serialize the string and the image data using a `DataOutputStream` wrapped around a `FileOutputStream`. As a fancy version of that, you could define a class to contain the text and the image, have that class implement `Serializable`, and serialize it to a file. Alternatively, you could serialize the image data as a base-64 string and then put the text and the base-64 image data into an XML document or JSON string. Other approaches are also possible.

If you provide more details about what kind of process will consume this file after it has been transferred, perhaps we can provide more focused suggestions.

Comment: I would like to transfer it over Wifi to PC running windows 7 or 8 where the receiving application should be able to access the metadata/file attributes.